# Invert image displayed by imshow in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I wanted the `imshow()` function in `matplotlib.pyplot` to display images the opposite way, i.e upside down. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Specify the keyword argument `origin='lower'` or `origin='upper'` in your call to `imshow`.

Comment: why does default differ on different machines? Is there a way to set the default? Thanks for this answer nonetheless, in the past I tried to fix this by using matrix flips and stuff. This is much easier!

Comment: probably because of different versions of pyplot (they changed the convention somewhere from 0,0 being top-left to bottom-left)

Comment: What if you want to move it clockwise.

Comment: @RahmiPruitt See [Matplotlib rotate image file by X degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31401812/674039)

Comment: Note that set ylim overrides imshow's origin flag. You should use `plt.gca().set(ylim=(im.shape[0],0))` if you want imshow origin to be upper.

Answer (score 7):

Use `ax.invert_yaxis()` to invert the y-axis, or `ax.invert_xaxis()` to invert the x-axis.

Comment: I find that this solution works much better than the accepted answer when also using the `extent` option to label the axis.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `extent` argument. For example, if X values range from -10 and 10 and Y values range from -5 to 5, you should pass `extent=(-10,10,-5,5)` to `imshow()`.

Comment: Rather than mirroring the image vertically, it mirrors the axis marks. While not an answer the question it can be an alternative in some cases. In addition it remaps the axis to a new range instead of the pixel count used by `imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate image with NumPy: `np.rot90()`
Flip image with NumPy: `np.flip()`

e.g.
`plt.imshow(np.flip(img))`
`plt.show()`

OR

`plt.imshow(np.rot90())`
`plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ylim` according to your wishes;
Use `plt.gca().set(ylim=(im.shape[0],0))` for `Upper Origin`,
or  `plt.gca().set(ylim=(0,im.shape[0]))` for `Lower Origin`