# How to animate the position and orientation of a resized image about a data point on a Matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, physics

## Problem

I am trying to simulate the landing of an upright rocket. I can plot the point representation of the dynamics easily; however, in order to make this simulation look cool I would like to add a [picture representation](http://www.spacex.com/sites/all/themes/spacex2012/images/falcon9/falcon9-render.png) of the rocket. Basically all I want to do is refresh an image of the rocket, with a height of **L**, a width of **W**, a position of **(x,y)**, and an orientation of **ϕ**, where **(x,y)** and **ϕ** are determined from the rocket's data point.

What is currently happening is that the *.png* image is being plotted at every time step and not refreshing. My problem can easily be understood by the animation I have so far in this **[video](https://youtu.be/mEayGMJOx40)**. Please take a look at the animation portion of my **Python** code below. Any help is appreciated.

### Python Code

```python
# Initial and global vars
Earth  = Environment('Earth')
Falcon = Lander(Earth)
dt = 1. / 30.  # 30 fps


#///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# set up figure and animation
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False,
                     xlim=(0,150), ylim=(0,100))
ax.grid()
line,    = ax.plot([], 'o-', lw=2)
status   = ax.text(0.02, 0.50, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
im_fname = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/falcon9.png'
im       = img.imread(im_fname)

def init():
    """initialize animation"""
    line.set_data([], [])
    status.set_text('')
    return line, status

def animate(i):
    """perform animation step"""
    global Falcon, dt; Falcon.step(dt)
    x, y, vx, vy, theta, omega, mass = Falcon.state
    L, W, Isp = Falcon.params # Length and width of rocket
    line.set_data([Falcon.state[0], Falcon.state[1]])
    t         = Falcon.time_elapsed
    aax, aay  = Falcon.Drag()/mass
    theta     = np.degrees(theta)%360
    v         = np.linalg.norm([vx, vy])
    status.set_text('$Time = %.2f$\n' % t +
                    '$a_D = (%.2f, %.2f)$\n' % (aax, aay) +
                    '$v = %.2f$\n' % v +
                    '$angle = %.2f$\n' % theta +
                    '$mass = %.4f$\n' % mass)

    # Show Falcon9 image
    x_hat, y_hat = Falcon.Orientation() # in this orientation
    left, right  = x-W/2., x+W/2. # perimeter of object
    down, up     = y-L/2., y+L/2.
    ax.imshow(im, aspect='auto', extent=(left, right, down, up))
    return line, status

# Interval based on dt and time to animate one step
from time import time
t0       = time()
animate(0)
t1       = time()
interval = 1000 * dt - (t1 - t0)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=300,
                              interval=interval, blit=True, init_func=init)
ani.save('falcon9.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31402322/5067311) can help, but it seems to be computationally heavy, and the answerer suggests something like pygame (designed for quick animations) instead.

Comment: I don't want to switch to PyGame. I know this is possible in matplotlib, I just can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: The first code block in the linked answer shows you how you can rotate an image with `scipy.ndimage.rotate`. I just noted, as the answerer, that you should expect the result to be slow.

Comment: Yea, but then the problem is: when I set the extent of the image it is not respect to the new rotated image axis.