# How can I rotate a 3d array (nxnxn) by x degrees around x, y, and z axes?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, rotatetransform

I have a 3d array created with numpy, and I was wondering how I can rotate it by a custom angle, not just the `rot90` function that numpy has. Can anyone help?

The 3d matrix represents an image (such as a cube, or some other shape) ie

```
0:
1 1 1
1   1
1 1 1

1:
1   1

1   1

2:
1 1 1
1   1
1 1 1
```

EDIT:
Moved solution to answer

Comment: What does the array represent? Image? Plane? Lines? The answer to your question depends on what the array is supposed to be.

Comment: @tehhowch It is supposed to be a 3d image (ill edit post)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib rotate image file by X degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401812/matplotlib-rotate-image-file-by-x-degrees)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some trial and error I came up with some code for my purposes (0 means empty in the array, another number will mean a filled voxel.

```
def rotate(self, deg_angle, axis):
        d = len(self.matrix)
        h = len(self.matrix[0])
        w = len(self.matrix[0][0])
        min_new_x = 0
        max_new_x = 0
        min_new_y = 0
        max_new_y = 0
        min_new_z = 0
        max_new_z = 0
        new_coords = []
        angle = radians(deg_angle)

        for z in range(d):
            for y in range(h):
                for x in range(w):

                    new_x = None
                    new_y = None
                    new_z = None

                    if axis == "x":
                        new_x = int(round(x))
                        new_y = int(round(y*cos(angle) - z*sin(angle)))
                        new_z = int(round(y*sin(angle) + z*cos(angle)))
                    elif axis == "y":
                        new_x = int(round(z*sin(angle) + x*cos(angle)))
                        new_y = int(round(y))
                        new_z = int(round(z*cos(angle) - x*sin(angle)))
                    elif axis == "z":
                        new_x = int(round(x*cos(angle) - y*sin(angle)))
                        new_y = int(round(x*sin(angle) + y*cos(angle)))
                        new_z = int(round(z))

                    val = self.matrix.item((z, y, x))
                    new_coords.append((val, new_x, new_y, new_z))
                    if new_x < min_new_x: min_new_x = new_x
                    if new_x > max_new_x: max_new_x = new_x
                    if new_y < min_new_y: min_new_y = new_y
                    if new_y > max_new_y: max_new_y = new_y
                    if new_z < min_new_z: min_new_z = new_z
                    if new_z > max_new_z: max_new_z = new_z

        new_x_offset = abs(min_new_x)
        new_y_offset = abs(min_new_y)
        new_z_offset = abs(min_new_z)

        new_width = abs(min_new_x - max_new_x)
        new_height = abs(min_new_y - max_new_y)
        new_depth = abs(min_new_z - max_new_z)

        rotated = np.empty((new_depth + 1, new_height + 1, new_width + 1))
        rotated.fill(0)
        for coord in new_coords:
            val = coord[0]
            x = coord[1]
            y = coord[2]
            z = coord[3]

            if rotated[new_z_offset + z][new_y_offset + y][new_x_offset + x] == 0:
                rotated[new_z_offset + z][new_y_offset + y][new_x_offset + x] = val

        self.matrix = rotated
```

The way I use the above code is:

```
cube = Rect_Prism(20, 20, 20) # creates a 3d array similar to above example, just bigger
cube.rotate(20, "x")
cube.rotate(60, "y")
```

Rect_Prism creates a MxNxD matrix, but in this case NxNxN.

And result when printing:

```
                            # # # # # # # # # # # #          
                      # # #     #         # #       #        
                  # #           #   # # #           #        
              # #               # #                 #        
        # # #               # # # #                   #      
    # #               # # #       #                   #      
# # # # # # # # # # #             #                   #      
#                   #               #                   #    
  #                 #               #                   #    
  #                 #               #                   #    
  #                 #                 #                   #  
    #                 #               #                   #  
    #                 #               #                   #  
    #                 #                 #                 #  
      #                 #               #                 #  
      #                 #               # #               # #
      #                   #               #                 #
      #                   #               # # # # # # # # # #
      #                   #           # #                 #  
        #                   #   # # #               # # #    
        #                   # # #             # # #          
        #             # # # #             # #                
          #       # #         #     # # #                    
          #   # #             # # #                          
          # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Comment: Nifty function! How did you define the class "matrix"

Comment: For the one interested: `self.matrix` can be exchanged with a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: I am getting the following error when trying to implement this A.rotate(40,"x")  "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rotate'" Can someone comment on this?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) function.

The reason this is in scipy and not in numpy is that rotating an image 90 degrees is done by just chaning the indices of the array. However, if you want to rotate an image by some arbitrary degrees you have to deal with interpolation, which adds a whole new layer of complexity to the problem. This is because all the pixels in the original image "perfectly lines up with" pixels in the rotated image when you rotate it by a factor of 90 degrees. This is not the case in general when you rotate an image.

Comment: This function uses spline interpolation, and I got quite different results from using torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate, which uses bilinear interpolation by default (no options for spline interpolation).

Comment: Also tried skimage.transform.rotate. Got results different from torchvision and scipy. speechless...

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a rotation matrix and multiply your this matrix for your array. Here the information

[Wikipedea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) rotation matrix information

[An example for 2d rotating](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-6-numpy/examples/creating-a-rotation-matrix-in-numpy/)

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work on pixel/voxel images (or more specifically raster images). Rotation matrices are used in 3D and vector graphics, but you can't multiply a 1000x1000x3 matrix (1Mpix RGB image) by a 2x2 rotation matrix.

Comment: @YngveMoe I would say it does work: you need to use the "coordinate vector" for each of the raster points and calculate its new positions by multiplying it with the rotation matrices as explained in the links mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider a "vector" representation for your data, instead of the current "raster" representation.

A vector representation would mean that, instead of each "voxel" being defined by its position in a grid, you would have some sort of list of voxels, with actual 3D coordinates.

So instead of having an MxNxD matrix where each voxel is a "black/white" dot, you could have a Mx3 matrix, where each row is a point, with columns being X, Y and Z.

That way, you would multiply the list by a 3x3 rotation matrix, and get another list of transformed coordinates.

You would remain with the problem of "rendering" these vector points (or lines, better yet) to a raster matrix (either pixels or voxels, but your sample image looks like 3D info has been projected to 2D space). There are a lot of techniques for doing this.