# 3D rotation of numpy array by theta

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

I have this cube that ive displayed using voxels.

[image]

I need to rotate it like the image above.
I've tried `np.rot` and `scipy.ndimage.interpolate.rotate` with no success.

Could someone point me in the right direction

```
Cube = np.rand.rand(8,8,10) < .5
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection=‘3d’)
ax.voxels(cube)
Plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you need to display at a different angle or actually rotate the data. Definitely need to update your question with some code showing a sample of the data as well as how you're plotting it.

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49179544/9703451

Comment: Updated. Just need to rotate the data

Comment: @raphael thanks! think did what I needed it to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rotate a 3d array (nxnxn) by x degrees around x, y, and z axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097667/how-can-i-rotate-a-3d-array-nxnxn-by-x-degrees-around-x-y-and-z-axes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
ax.view_init(elev=None, azim=None)
plt.show()
```

elev = stores the elevation angle in the z plane.

azim = stores the azimuth angle in the x,y plane.